# Writing test case in Rspec to handle syntax error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-rails

I am new to Rspec. I am writing a spec for a controller. Is it possible to catch syntax errors in the code with spec i.e. I would like to write case for handling syntax error in controller with Rspec. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Ruby (and thus RSpec) will fail to run your code if you have syntax errors, and the exit code will be non-zero. That is another way of finding this case.

Answer (score 1):

in theory you could pass a piece of code as a string to `eval` or `load` a specific file that contains syntax errors and rescue those with `rescue Exception => e`.

but may i ask WHY?

Answer (score 0):

Use eval like bellow.

```
describe "Backreferences to Non-Existent Capturing Groups" do
  describe '/(a)b\1/' do
    it { expect { eval '"aba".match(/(a)\1/)' }.to_not raise_error }
  end

  describe '/(a)b\2/' do
    it { expect { eval '"aba".match(/(a)\2/)' }.to raise_error(SyntaxError) }
  end
end
```